# Seem to be able to construct function on the whole real line from the value in a finite interval. What is wrong with the argument?

Tags: hermite-polynomials

I have a question I am phrasing in terms of expansion of a function in terms of Hermite polynomials but it applies to other expansions as well.

First I establish my convention for Hermite polynomials which is

$$
(-1)^n   \partial_z^n \varphi(z)= H_n(z) \varphi(z)
$$

where $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$. Under this the first few Hermite polynomials are

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
H_0 &=& 1 \\
H_1 &=& z \\
H_2 &=& z^2-1 \\
\dots
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now we can expand a function in Hermite polynomials

$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n H_n(z)
$$

and we can extract the coefficients by

$$
c_n = \frac{1}{n!} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz~ \varphi(z) H_n(z) f(z)
$$

All this is fine. What I want to know what is the problem with the following. Suppose I have the function value only in the interval $z \in [a,b]$ and we compute

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde c_m &=&  \frac{1}{m!} \int_{a}^b dz~ \varphi(z) H_m(z) f(z) \\
&=& \frac{1}{m!} \int_{a}^b dz~ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n ~\varphi(z) H_m(z) H_n(z) \\
&{\bf \color{blue}{\stackrel{?}{=}}}& \frac{1}{m!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  c_n \int_{a}^b dz~  ~\varphi(z) H_m(z) H_n(z) \\
&=& \frac{1}{m!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma_{m,n} c_n
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where I have defined

$$
\gamma_{m,n} := \int_{a}^b dz~  ~\varphi(z) H_m(z) H_n(z)
$$

which can be evaluated explicitly. My question is I can have two functions that are the same in the interval $z \in [a,b]$. $\gamma_{m,n}$ are independent of the function and therefore I cannot see how the above can be true. Said differently it seems I can invert the relation and from $\tilde c_m$ get the *true* $c_n$ which is ridiculous because I should not be able to read of the full function on the real line from the value inside an interval. So what am I doing wrong? I suspect the problem is with the step that I put a question mark on but what is specifically the problem?

Comment: How do you know that the mapping from the $c_n$ to the $\tilde c_m$ is invertible?

Comment: Yes I don't know if $\frac{1}{m!} \gamma_{m,n}$ is invertible given that its infinite dimensional matrix. Any ideas on how to check this?

Comment: Well, I havent thought deeply about your question, but I suspect that in fact the mapping is not invertible in general, for exacly the reason that you give: there are many different functions with the same restriction to $[a,b]$.

Comment: I guess I could simplify the problem by taking a finite box and using $\sin,\cos$ as the basis. Then $\gamma_{m,n}$ would be more tractable but would still be an infinite dimensional matrix and I wouldn't know how to check if its invertible or not. Having said that the possibility of several functions that have same restriction in $[a,b]$ is rigorous enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that a general function cannot be determined by its values on any finite interval, but *if you know* that the function is given by a power series, for example, then it is determined by its values on any interval, however small.  This isn't really all that surprising.  If we know that a function is a quadratic polynomial, then it is determined by its values at three points.

Comment: Yes but in my case I do not know anything about $f(z)$ to begin with. All I am saying is that any function on the real line can be expanded in Hermites. Now it seems from the way I wrote above that knowing it in an interval allows me to extract all the coefficients (which is clearly wrong).